# SignalR communication between different .net platforms

Tags: c#, angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I currently have a WCF project running .NET 4.6.1 and a .NET Core project through which I am running a web service and an Angular 2 app. When trying to reference the AspNetCore.SignarlR project (from the WCF project) using the HubConnection class, when the connection is started I am always receiving an error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

The Angular app is successfully using the SignalR service for a chat demo. I definitely have my routing defined in the correct order and the name of my hub across projects has been double checked too.

Could the error I be receiving be related to the fact I'm using two different implementations of the SignalR library? If so, is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Core version of SignalR is not compatible with the previous version. Note that the client is targeting netstandard so you should be able to use the .NET Client from the ASP.NET Core version of SignalR in your project just fine.

Having said that - I think you are not hitting the version incompatibility yet. The error message complains about the character `<` which tells me that the server is serving either XML or HTML (possibly an error) while the client (either the old one or the new one) expects JSON in the first response. You need to first check what is the response the server returned to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right it's returning an HTML document instead. What's interesting is if I create a server side web request to http://localhost:50114/myhub, it successfully returns a valid json response with the connection ID. If I use the HubConnection("http://localhost:50114/myhub", false); approach, the connection id is always null

Comment: What's in the HTML? Are you locally running with IIS or just Kestrel? Maybe  it's IIS misconfiguration?

Comment: I finally managed to see the client was making a call which had a variety of different querystring params that included something about negotiation. The Angular app made a call that didn't include this parameter, so the pipeline dealt with it correctly. I'm assuming the URL did not match what the aspnetcore version of signalr was expecting. The HTML being returned was just the default page from the Angular app. For now I've accepted that this approach probably isn't the best to take for now.